# How to pass two paths to one image view in next activity

Tags: android

I have two activities in first activity i capture the image and send the preview to another activity and i have a gallery button through which image preview is send to image view to next activity.So how can i code to set two paths of images in one image view.Please help me

My first activity:

```
  PictureCallback  myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  Intent i = new Intent(context, PassActivity.class);
    // String value = "hello";
    // i.putExtra("camera", value);
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putByteArray("photo", data);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
 //   startActivity(i);
   // Toast.makeText(CodeActivity.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // setResult(0);
startActivityForResult(i,CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
};

public void sendImage(){

    intent = new Intent(context,PassActivity.class);
    extras = new Bundle();
    //image = img.getDrawingCache();

    //extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", picturePath);
    extras.putCharSequence("path",pictureFile);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
    //startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

My second activity:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent datas) {



     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, datas);

     if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {

        //  previewCapturedImage();
  //   }

          //Toast.makeText(PassActivity.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//} 

         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
         byte[] photo = new byte [2048];
        photo = extras.getByteArray("photo");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo , 0, photo .length);
        imgss.setImageBitmap(bmp);*/



        }

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE)



        {

            imgss.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgsec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String path =  extras.get("path").toString();

            Log.i("VALUE",path);
            imgsec.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));

        }

    }


        /*private void previewCapturedImage() {
            try {
                // hide video preview

                // imgsec.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //  imgss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                 byte[] data = new byte [2048];
                data = extras.getByteArray("photo");
                 final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
                 imgss.setRotation(90);
                imgss.setImageBitmap(bmp);  

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use: *getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra("path");* in *onCreate()* method of the second activity (PassActivity i think)?

Comment: Yes,with this code the image is showing.But I want that both the paths are passings to one image view and it is show nothing on the next activity.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I want that both the paths are passings to one image view and it is show nothing on the next activity*"? can you please explain more?

Comment: The paths of gallery and captured image are sending to the next activity foe preview

Comment: If you want to pass 2 values from ActivityOne to ActivityTwo, you only need to use 2 extras, one for the "galleryPath" and the second for "imagePath" (eg: bundle.putByteArray("photo", data); and bundle.putCharSequence("path",pictureFile);). Then you can get their values from your second activity by *getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra("path");* for example. Is that your problem?

Comment: Yes,but in second activity the image view is one so at that time when i pass two paths then in second activity it gives null pointer exception.

Comment: The only reason to get a NullPointerExcepion= is to pass a null value as a path. Mention that calling *PassActivity.class* from *sendImage()* is not the same as calling it from *onPictureTaken()* : in the first call you pass only the path and in the second one you pass only the photo, maybe this is why you have the NullPE in your second activity, because one of them(path or photo) is always missing. Another thing: i think you must get your data in onCreate() method and not in onActivityResult(), because onActivityResult() is calling when you came back to the activity not at this creation.

Comment: I have given the condition in oncreate but same the preview on next activity is not showing.